# Will planting Pachysandra terminalis affect existing shrubs?

Tags: plant-health, shrubs, growth, ground-cover

I'm considering planting [*Pachysandra terminalis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachysandra_terminalis) around the base of a few shrub/tree stands, but am concerned it may negatively effect the growth of the existing trees/shrubs.

- The first area is around the base of 4 established 8-10' Emerald Green Arborvitae.
- The second is around a mixture of 2-3' [Green Giant Thuja, *Thuja (standishii x plicata)* 'Green Giant'](http://www.usna.usda.gov/Newintro/grgiant.pdf), [Leyland Cyprus, *Cupressus × leylandii*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyland_cypress), and [Japenese Cedar, *Cryptomeria japonica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptomeria_japonica) that were planted this spring.

Do you think it's safe to plant the Pachysandra this fall without jeopardizing the existing plantings?

Answer (score 3):

The Pachysandra itself won't negatively affect growth - what might, though, is if you break a lot of roots when digging to plant it if you attempt to plant too close to your trees. Most conifers produce a mat of roots fairly near the surface, with a taproot going deep down, so you'll need to plant far enough away that the roots of the trees aren't compromised, particularly with the 4 established Thuja - won't be so difficult round the more recently planted ones, but even so, you will need to take account of any root spread and plant a distance away, not least so that the two plants aren't competing too much for nutrients and water.